# Firefox url problem

Tags: asp.net, firefox, url, redirect, url-encoding

I check the session information when I go to default.aspx if session is null return login.aspx

```
 if (Session[SessionMemberKey] == null)
 {
      Response.Redirect("http://site.com/Login.aspx");
 }
```

Firefox is going to this page http://site.com/%5CLogin.aspx

It is working in Chrome and IE.

Comment: It's going to the right page, right? You're complaining about the %5C format?

Answer (score 2):

The %5C is URL-encoding for the backslash \.

When I accessed your site, this was what appeared in my Firefox address bar:

http://admin.duuzo.com/Pages\Membership\Login.aspx

I got the login page correctly, though.

Check this out:

[firefox auto-adds %5Cimg%5C in URL link to image](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=398596)

Answer (score 2):

I just pulled the site up in Firefox.

The code you posted isn't what is actually being used.  It looks like you are actually building that path and instead of using forward slashes (/) you are using backslashes () in the path.